# How to use glTexImage2D to fill an RGB texture and show it?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a `ByteBuffer` with an RGB frame from a video, so it has size `1280x720x3`.

I want to render it using OpenGL. Here's my fragment shader:

```java
public static final String videoFragment =
    "#version 320 es\n"+
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform float alpha;\n" +
    "uniform sampler2D sampler;\n"+
    "\n" +
    "in vec2 TexCoord;\n" +
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n" +
    "void main()\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "    vec4 rgba;\n" +
    "    rgba.rgb = texture(sampler, TexCoord).rgb;\n" +
    "    rgba.a = 1.0f;\n" +
    "    //FragColor = vec4(1.0f,0,0,1.0f);\n" +
    "    FragColor = rgba;\n" +
    "}\n";
```

How should I fill it using `glTexImage2D`? I want to put my RGB data into it. I tried many combinations of `GLES20.GL_RGB` and others but they won't work or I simply get a black and white image:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GLES20.?,
    1280,
    720,
    0,
    GLES20.?,
    GLES20.?,
    buffer);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the video format is RGB? Is it something different, [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just checked with the media codec decoder output and I'm getting https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities#COLOR_Format32bitABGR8888 which is RGBA (8888)

Comment: In that case the format is `GL_RGBA`, the internal format is the same and the type is `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.